# SQL - Cost of indexing NULL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I want to learn cost of using an unfiltered index which indexes all existing values, also NULL values.

Should I avoid using unfiltered index?

I am using MS SQL Server 13

The table has already two indexes and mainly insert commands are running on this table. The values of column I want to create index on are mainly not null. Only 1% of values are null.

Comment: If you really only expect 1% of values to be `NULL`, then I don't see any reason to use a filtered index.

Comment: Given that filtered indexes haven't always existed in the product but `NULL` has for a very long time, why is your "default" option a filtered index?

Comment: I will replace NULL values soon by updating our app. But NULL values will come for a few weeks. I just want to be sure that my db performance will stay good until I update app.I am just cruious. I read a lot about this topic and wanted to ask experienced people :)

Comment: Well, only you have your database structures, only you have your data and existing indexes, only you know the query patterns in this database. You're the only one who can *measure it* and find out.

Comment: Thnaks  @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: You say "_I will replace NULL values soon by updating our app_", what does that mean?

Comment: I have these values at other table. I will update our app and this column will not be NULL. I will be able to search this table faster by using index.

Comment: Don't worry too much, null values aren't dangerous.